# Is there a high-level way to read in lines from an output file and have the types recognized by the structure of the contents?

Tags: python, string, tuples

Suppose I have an output file that I want to read and each line was created by joining several types together, prepending and appending the list braces,

```
[('tupleValueA','tupleValueB'), 'someString', ('anotherTupleA','anotherTupleB')]
```

I want to read the lines in.  Now I can read them in, and operate on the string to assign values and types but I was wondering if Python had a higher level method for this.

After building a function to do this I tried to find a higher level approach but didn't find one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is [eval](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#eval). But please keep in mind that this function will evaluate and execute the lines. So don't run it on untrusted input ever!

```
>>> print eval("[('tupleValueA', 1), 'someString']")
[('tupleValueA', 1), 'someString']
```

If you have control over the script that generate the output file, then I would suggest you use [json](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html) encoding. JSON format is very similar to the python string representation of lists and dictionaries. And will be much more secure and robust to read from.

```
>>> import json
>>> json.dumps(['foo', {'bar': ('baz', None, 1.0, 2)}])
'["foo", {"bar": ["baz", null, 1.0, 2]}]'
>>> json.loads('["foo", {"bar": ["baz", null, 1.0, 2]}]')
["foo", {"bar": ["baz", null, 1.0, 2]}]
```

Comment: Thank you so much, why couldn't I find this.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you describe is conventionally referred to as [serialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization).  [JavaScript Object Notation (JSON)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) is one popular serialization protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Probably it would be better to store the data with a module like [pickle](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html) in the first place, instead of using normal strings. This way you avoid a lot of problems that come with `eval` and get a more robust solution.

Comment: Well Pickling will not work.  See my question from yesterday. The list is 8 million lines long and when pickled has 379,000 keys.  Even when I break the file into three pieces and read them as needed it puts too much of a load.  I don't want to go to a database as the keys are unique identifiers and the table columns would be dates (about 3600).  But thanks